# How to capitalize the first letter of a paragraph with jquery but no symbols?

Tags: jquery, capitalize

In my worpdress blog i am using the following jquery code to wrap the first letter in a span tag so i can style it with a bigger appearance:

```
$(".single .the_content p:first")
  .each(function () { var el = $(this), replace(/\b[a-z]/g, text = el.html(), first = text.slice(0, 1), rest = text.slice(1); el.html("<span class='capital'>" + first + "</span>" + rest); });
```

It's works ok but, when i insert an image does not display because the first symbol of the image insert code "<" i'ts wrapped in span tags, so, how can i apply this only to letters from a to z ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `':first-letter` css pseudo-element

If you add css like so:

```
.single .the_content p:first-letter {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #80ffff;
}
```

Or something of the sort, that should cover it.

( oh, right, with the `:first-child` css pseudo-element )

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that would style the first letter of a series of paragraphs with a larger appearance and float it left, similar to the style seen in magazines.

```
p:first-child:first-letter {
    font-size: 5em;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jrthib/du4qv/1/

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/

Comment: Great! i really appreciate your help! @DomDay